# Animating a floated div

Tags: css, css-float, css-animations

I'm trying to achieve the effect of a horizontal accordion using exclusively CSS for animations and layout. So I have 4 columns set up and the main difference with a classic accordion is that when I click on a column, instead of expanding in one direction, it should expand in both directions and push the other columns left and right.

Here's a compact version of my code right now : http://jsfiddle.net/4ZGmj/183/

If you click on the red column, it works exactly as intended: the column is expanded in both directions and all other columns are pushed to the right. Now if you click on the green column, you'll notice something different: the column expands in both directions as intended, but it only pushes columns to the right while overlapping the column to the left. What I would like is for each column to push all neighboring columns when expanded.

I guess it might have to do with the fact that my columns are floated left. Do you guys have any insight on what is causing this behavior and what I can do to fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite sure how to fix it, but I think you're on the right track with the float: left. If you change it to float: right, the behavior is changed significantly.

Comment: @Stano, you are right, the negative margin seems to be the cause. Only if I remove it then the divs won't expand in both directions, which is the primary intended effect. Also I am actually using Firefox, but the code is intended to run on an iPad so I have to code for Safari, that's why I'm using -webkit-

Comment: @DrunkenBeard Ok, I only recommend Firefox because it has great web development tools. Tried to make some [modification](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZGmj/184/), it is not perfect and also not as easy as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it and get the intended effect by removing the negative margin value from the "animate" class (this was responsible for expanding in both ways, but also caused the overlapping to the left). Instead, I added a new class "pushleft" that has this negative margin value and that I always apply to the first column. You can see the effect and get a better understanding of the idea here : http://jsfiddle.net/4ZGmj/185/

Thanks for your help, I wouldn't have fixed it if it wasn't for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue may be in the .animate class, where you give it a **negative** 50px margin. Negative margins overlap the "previous" element (in all directions). If you remove the -50px, the images will only "flow" to the right, since they're "glued" via the float:left property, which will not do what you want anyway :(

I think the way to get around this is by using relative dimensions. Try setting up a div with a fixed width and use relative dimensions (like 25% for each). You probably have to set a behavior on the :not clicked divs aswell.

Like, if one div is ".animated", it has 33% width, while the others would have around 22%...
There's probably a better math you can arrange for it, though!

edit: typo

Comment: Thanks for your input. The negative margin seems to be the cause indeed. I'll look into your solution.